# Javascript validate username on PHP with realtime output

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use Javascript to validate my input username if it is correct or not showing result on realtime.
Here is index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str){
    if(str.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "";
    }else{
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo3.php?input=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Type a username: <br>
<input id="hint" type="text" name="username" oninput="showHint(this.value)"><p id="hint"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo3.php code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","123456","mini");

$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['input']);
$sql = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows){
        echo "Valid username";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid username";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the oninput event example from w3cschools, and I am wondering why my result do not show what I expect?
And if I assign $username with static variable, demo3.php result seems to be correct feedback, not from index.html.

Plus, I am wondering how to validate multiple forms, such as password and email within the same validation php file.
Ex:

```
input1 -> check username ->output check result
input2-> check password ->output check result
input3-> check email->output check result
```

New to javascript.All the tutorial seems to provide only one demo, not multiple examples.

Comment: After your `$result` line, add in this `echo($result);` and see if anything comes back.

Comment: Check what the value of `$_REQUEST['input']` is, is it what you are expecting?

Comment: @jonmrich echo result would show nothing, after I assign it with correct username, use var_dump($result) it shows correct result on demo3.php, but index.html still no result.

Comment: One thing: if you are creating a pure php file, you don't need to put html on it. Just put all your code inside <?php ?> and get rid of the empty html/body tags.

Comment: Did you tried to POST to your `demo3.php` file directly? Do you have some error in your browser console?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek no luck, request and post get same null result.

Comment: @PietroCoelho I use F12 to check console but no error message..tried POST but username seems to be NULL, no idea why it cause that, my another studies use the same way to retrieve data from user input, no success on this project.

Comment: @newbrant It might be that you are doing `xmlhttp.open("POST", ... )`, but your variable is a `GET` (as it's in the URL). Try changing it to `xmlhttp.open("GET", ... )`. If that happens to work, I would be happy to add it as an answer. You can also check the array directly, just `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, and see what's in it. As it may be in there, just not accessed correct. You can do the same with `$_POST` and/or `$_GET`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Super Hero, THANK YOU! It works!

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek One more question, if I want to validate password as well and put function to be on the <form> tag, the xmlhttp seems to get only one responseText from demo3.php, can I validate different user input and show validation message from one single file? Or I have to do it for each validation under the input function.

Comment: @newbrant Generally you want to avoid placing a password in the URL. But for `GET` you can add more items to the URL using `&` between each item. For example `"demo3.php?input=" + str1 + "&input2=" + str2` Will have a `input` and an `input2`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks for quick reply, the URL I got it, only concern is that demo3.php, the "echo" result from demo3.php seems to be unique result from response.Text added to input1, but what if I want to add message to input2, from Unique response.Text, no idea how to show message2 to input2 from demo3.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input is being placed in the URL, you will need to use the `GET` parameter other than `POST` (which does not use the URL):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo3.php?input=" + str, true);
```

Now it should be able to pickup your `input` for `$_REQUEST['input']` or `$_GET['input']`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the ID "hint" twice. ID is a unique identifier, so you NEVER should use it more than once in the same page. And you should avoid using inline handlers. You need to change your javascript to:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 function showHint(str){
    if(str.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "";
    }else{
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo3.php?input=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
 }

 document.getElementById("hintInput").onkeyup = function() {
  showHint(this.value)
 }
}
</script>
```

and your HTML:

```
<input id="hintInput" type="text" name="username"><p id="hint"></p>
```

You can get rid of `window.onload` if you place your script tag before closing the `body` tag.

Comment: thanks for the tip, tried window.onload, but no success to display message, might study more about window.onload later. Now may try the simple function, correct id, now show the message, and add "echo "Invalid username". " And username is " . $username;" to the demo3.php, question is that username seems to be NULL, no username shows up, can you help to figure out what's wrong with demo3.php, thank you.